# Download notification not showing after factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, download-manager

I have an Asus Zenfone 5.

Usually when I am downloading a file, my mobile will show the download in the notification pane. After performing a factory reset on the device it is not showing the download notification. I think the built in download manager is damaged after factory reset.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A factory reset **does not** touch the system partition, so built in apps such as the built in Download manager will not get touched. Perhaps you used a different web browser before the factory reset you performed, and that had better download management than the one you are currently using.

If you download ES File Explorer from the play store, you can use the module in that app called ES Downloader. This is a good way to check downloads in progress in a nice dialogue box

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with this app just follow these steps definitely your problem would be fixed.

Go to setting 
Open uc browser 
Just click on notification check box

That's it , enjoy

Answer (score 0):

very easy problem. go to setting select app switch to all and find Download Manager. you will see unchecked Show Notification. Check that with your nose. :)

Comment: That does tend to work, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings->Application Manager->Click the Menu button->Sort by size/Reset App Preference->Click Reset App Preference.